# asp.net: response.redirect - dealing with threadabortedexception

Tags: asp.net

when using response.redirect(url) it throws a threadabortedexception. Using the overload and setting endResponse to false will not throw the exception but will let the execution finish.

Is it better to catch and ignore the threadabortedexception or to use the overload and set endResponse to false?

No other code needs to be executed after the redirect call and all resources are cleaned up already. There is error logging and default actions in the global.asax so allowing the exception to bubble up isn't possible.

Comment: Have you tried a redirect with the bool flag set, immeditaly followed by something like response.end ?

Comment: response.end is what throws the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced this as well. In this case, you can just use the overload.

Comment: what are the implications of using the overload? The point of this app is to do some logic on the incoming url parameters and then redirect. It has to be as fast as possible.

Comment: There are no implicit implications especially since no other code needs to be executed as you stated.

Comment: based on what @Aliostad posted, i think this is going to be safer than catching the exception.

Answer (score 2):

[ThreadAbortException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx) can be caught but cannot be handled.

> When a call is made to the Abort
>   method to destroy a thread, the common
>   language runtime throws a
>   ThreadAbortException.
>   ThreadAbortException is a special
>   exception that can be caught, but it
>   will automatically be raised again at
>   the end of the catch block.

**This is how ASP.NET works**. Redirect **by design** throws a thread abort exceptions, **just ignore it**.

Comment: strange, it doesn't actually do that